# Retaining label values in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I want retain value of label in view after existing the view, so that it shows the old value when reopening the view. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a [model object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) to store the state of the label so that the view can be repopulated with the correct values when needed.